# PHP Routing based on arrays, How to match * to anything

Tags: php, regex, arrays, url-routing

I have an array containing all routes/urls and their path,

```
Example : $route = array(
'/' => 'files/index.php',
'pages' => 'files/pages.php',
'pages/add' => 'files/page-add.php',
'posts/*' => 'files/posts.php',
)
```

Using array_key_exists() i check if a route exists in the array and if yes then load its path and it works if a direct match is found.

I want it to match to `posts/*` path whenever a request is made to `posts/anything, posts/view/10`, And i cannot do this using array_key_exists().

Do you guys have any ideas/suggestions on which method i should use?

Comment: I'd say your solving the wrong problem, take a look at what you can do with your .htaccess file as this will easily map paths to files.

Comment: Yeah it does, But i am using Plugin like architecture, As soon as a Plugin is activated, It can register for routes and those routes are stored in array, This helps with the performance and i still get plugin like system... I am using htaccess as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a combination of two strategies:

- stick with your 'routing array' for the direct matches, that is a secure solution with good performance.
- for remaining requests that gave no direct match try additional strategies like a regular expression based pattern matching, typically using phps `preg_match()` function. This gives you endless possibilities to describe patterns, though it obviously is slower than looking for direct matches.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `array_key_exists()`, and it fails, then try routes where you detect a `*` in the key.

```
if (array_key_exists($url, $route)) {
   // Serve normally.
} else {

    $route = array_filter($route, function($route) { 
                     if (substr($route, -1) != "*") {
                        return FALSE;
                     }

                     return (substr($url, 0, strlen($route)) != substr($route, 0, -1));
               });

    if ($route) {
       // Serve normally.
       $route = end($route);

    } else {
       // Route wasn't matched.
    }

}
```